# IPython Notebook: code reuse

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reusability, code-reuse

Is it possible to plug IPython notebook into existing Python project and to be able to reuse some of the existing code w/o copy-pasting it into a notebook?

I am looking for a way to use IPython Notebooks as a part of a large Python project to quickly test hypothesis and to analyze data on the spot.

**P.S.** It would also be nice to be able to import Python files into a Notebook. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but I want to answer it if someone still looks it up.

> P.S. It would also be nice to be able to import Python files into a Notebook. Is it possible?

You can import any python script (`filexy.py`) from the same folder as your notebook by simply stating `import filexy`.

Relating to that, I'd suggest that you define functions for your most reused code bits and gather them in a library (`filexy.py`) that you import in your notebook. Use the notebook as a short, clean, "working-desk" and your `filexy.py` library as the "toolbox".

That way you can also solve:

> I am looking for a way to use IPython Notebooks as a part of a large Python project to quickly test hypothesis and to analyze data on the spot.